# Is there an option to execute javascript file only on plugin deactivation

Tags: javascript, deactivation

I'm creating a custom plugin for WordPress and I'm trying to execute `javascript` file only on plugin deactivation.

I'm using `register_deactivation_hook()` and `wp_enqueue_script()` to execute file only on plugin deactivation.

There are no errors in the code since the `javascript` code works well if it is called outside the `register_deactivation_hook()`

This is what I've tried so far:

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivation' );
function deactivation() {
    function delete_rest_api() {
        wp_enqueue_script('deactivation_data_api', plugins_url('assets/js/deactivation_data_api.js', __FILE__));
    }
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'delete_rest_api' );
}
```

In the end, the plugin needs to execute that `javascript` file only during plugin deactivation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need to do via JavaScript on deactivation? Judging by the file name, you need to interact with an API? If so, you can/should do that with PHP.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes, you are right. But complete `API` is already done with `JS` and everything work, so, just I need to call that file on the deactivation hook. Do you have any solution for that? Thanks